# datagridview to textbox binding data

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

When the program is executed, the datagridview populate data and also the textboxes(example StockNumber,Description) and when i typed words in the search textbox ,the datagridview filters the matching words.When I clicked the item in the datagridview the textboxes does not changed it didnt show the information...

what the solution for my problem..i need to display the information in the textboxes when i clicked the item in the datagridview..

```
Private Sub txtreg_delsrch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtreg_delsrch.TextChanged

    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\sony\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Inventory\ItemInventory.mdb")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT StockNo,Item,Description,Reference,Quantity,Unit FROM Supplies_Regular WHERE Description Like '%" & txtreg_delsrch.Text & "%'", con)
    con.Open()
    Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "MyTable")
    Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable").DefaultView

End Sub
```

Comment: here's my screenshot for my problem http://i233.photobucket.com/albums/ee298/killua25b/search.png

Comment: by the way i have solved the problem now..thank all for your replies^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx):

```
Dim binding = New BindingSource() 
    With { .DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable") }
Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.DataSource = binding
StockNumber_textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", binding, "StockNo")
```

Last line simply binds your object's `StockNo` property to `TextBox.Text`.

Comment: the textboxes are already binded.my problem sir is when it filters the item and when i clicked the item the textboxes didnt change it is like it freezes when i typed words in the search textbox

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in the Grid `CellClick` event.

```
    Dim row As Integer = e.RowIndex
    Dim col As Integer = e.ColumnIndex

    textbox.Text = grid.Item(col, row).value
```